# Cell with Datagridviewcombobox column displays the ValueMember instead of DisplayMember

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview that bounds data from database.

```
 DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colOperationID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
 colOperationID.Name = "OperationID";
 colOperationID.DataPropertyName = "OperationID";
 BOMOperations.Columns.Add(colOperationID);

 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colOperationDesc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
 colOperationDesc.Name = "OperationDesc";
 colOperationDesc.DataSource = srcDT;
 colOperationDesc.DisplayMember = "OperationDesc";
 colOperationDesc.ValueMember = "OperationID";
 colOperationDesc.DataPropertyName = "OperationDesc";
 colOperationDesc.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
 colOperationDesc.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
 colOperationDesc.DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = true;
 BOMOperations.Columns.Add(colOperationDesc);
```

Then the user will click edit button, the datagridview will become editable. My problem is when I click on datagridviewcombobox column then I will choose an item, the item will display in correctly(the DisplayMember) but as long as the cell lost focus, the cell of the combobox displays the ValueMember.

I already tried the solution i got here to check on the datatype, but mine is corrent. The DisplayValue is a string while the DisplayValue is an int.

I tried also to change the following line `colOperationDesc.DataPropertyName = "OperationDesc";` to `colOperationDesc.DataPropertyName = "OperationID";` and it gives me this exception. [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyM3l.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colOperationDesc.DataPropertyName` should be a name of the column in `DataGridView.DataSource` and should "refer" to same value as in `colOperationDesc.ValueMember`.

Notice that `colOperationDesc.ValueMember` and `colOperationDesc.DisplayMember` should be property/column names from `colOperationDesc.DataSource` in your case from `srcDT` variable.

> but as long as the cell lost focus, the cell of the combobox displays
>   the ValueMember

This happened because column/property "OperationDesc" (`DisplayMember`) not found from `srcDT` variable.

Comment: I already tried to change colOperationDesc.DataPropertyName = "OperationID" but it is giving me a System.Exception <SelectedValue(DisplayMember)> is not a valid value for Int32.

Comment: @Zhyke - please check that properties/columns used in `colOperationDesc.ValueMember` and `colOperationDesc.DisplayMember` exists in `srcDT` variable

Comment: they do exists in the datatable srcDT. I updated my post and uploaded the exception i got when i change the DataPropertyName. Here is the code for my datasource: `cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    srcDT = new DataTable();

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT OperationID, OperationDesc FROM Operation";
                    srcDT = _SQL.GetData(cmd);

                   

                    colOperationDesc.DataSource = srcDT;
                    colOperationDesc.ValueMember = "OperationID";
                    colOperationDesc.DisplayMember = "OperationDesc";`

Comment: @Zhyke, `DataPropertyName` should refer to column from `DataTable` used in DataGridView.DataSource` and be **exactly same** type as "OperationId" in `srcDT`. Did you use selected value somewhere in the code? Which line throws exception?

Comment: Yes, they do have the same column name and same data type. I am using the selected value changed to populate other fields in my datagridview. Actually the exception is only a popup dialog. Thanks.

Comment: I already resolved the issue. I just added the following code in the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged events and it works now. ` BOMOperations.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);`. Thank you so much for the help and I will accept your answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `DataPropertyName` to be `OperationID`.

```
colOperationDesc.DataPropertyName = "OperationID";
```

Comment: thanks but I already tried that one and it's giving me an System.Exception: <SelectedValue(DisplayMember)> is not a valid value for Int32.